# TypeError: string indices must be integers while reading the json

Tags: python, json, pandas

While reading the json requests, I'm getting

```
TypeError: string indices must be integers error.
```

Below is the request

```
"{'Name': 'XYZ', 'Details': [{'Name': 'hhh', 'Price': '5.79'}, 
{'Name': ' abc', 'Price': '2.79'},
 {'Name': 'def', 'Price': '2.99'}, 
 {'Name': ' ghi', 'Price': '1.29'}, 
{'Name': 'ijk',  'Price': '1.49'}]}"
```

I want to get values of Details key from the above request.

I tried the below, none of them are working

```
data = json.loads(req)

data = json.dumps(req)

ast.literal_eval(data).
```

Comment: That's not valid JSON (single quotes instead of double), but your error message is completely irrelevant. Post your whole code please.

Comment: Your example is not functional. `req` is not a valid JSON structure. You `req` variable should be `'''{"XName": "XYZ", "Details": [{"Name": "abc", "Price": "3.2"}, {"Name": "def", "Price": "4.5"}]}'''`

Comment: have edited the request. plz check now

Comment: JSON does not allow single quotes. `'Name'` must be `"Name"`.

Comment: How do you get `request`? if you get it from `r = requests.get(url)`, use `r.text` to get the json string. `r.json()` to get the `dict`.

Answer (score 1):

If your `req` variable is defined as follows:

```
req = '{"Name": "XYZ", "Details": [{"Name": "hhh", "Price": "5.79"}, {"Name": "abc", "Price": "2.79"}, {"Name": "def", "Price": "2.99"},  {"Name": "ghi", "Price": "1.29"}, {"Name": "ijk",  "Price": "1.49"}]}'
```

You can use [`pd.json_normalize`](https://pandas.pydata.org/docs/reference/api/pandas.json_normalize.html):

```
df = pd.json_normalize(json.loads(req), 'Details', ['Name'], meta_prefix='X') \
       .astype({'Price': float})
```

```
>>> df
  Name  Price XName
0  hhh   5.79   XYZ
1  abc   2.79   XYZ
2  def   2.99   XYZ
3  ghi   1.29   XYZ
4  ijk   1.49   XYZ

>>> df.info()
<class 'pandas.core.frame.DataFrame'>
RangeIndex: 5 entries, 0 to 4
Data columns (total 3 columns):
 #   Column  Non-Null Count  Dtype
---  ------  --------------  -----
 0   Name    5 non-null      object
 1   Price   5 non-null      float64
 2   XName   5 non-null      object
dtypes: float64(1), object(2)
memory usage: 248.0+ bytes
```